# Remove from a div by class name from post page if post author role is not administrator

Tags: plugin-development, functions, javascript, user-roles

I have a site with two type of user role, administrator and author.

I have a dive class name "site-shop-wrapper" which I want to show only to posts added by the administrator and hide it for all other posts added by authors.

So basically I need a function to check the post author role and if it was not an administrator, then remove the div by class name.

I am new to WP and don't know much about it, any help with bee appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share your existing query/loop?

Comment: Hi @megmorsie please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I decided to use if author_can function. However, I believe there is a better way of doing this.
`add_action('wp_footer', 'remove_buybutton_from_non_admin');
function remove_buybutton_from_non_admin(){
    if (author_can($post->ID, 'activate_plugins')) {
        ?>
            <script>
                var appBanners = document.getElementsByClassName('shop-wrapper'), i;
                    for (i = 0; i < appBanners.length; i += 1) {
                        appBanners[i].style.visibility="show";
                    }
            </script>
        <?php
    }
    else {
        ?>
            <script>
                var appBanners = document.getElementsByClassName('shop-wrapper'), i;
                    for (i = 0; i < appBanners.length; i += 1) {
                    appBanners[i].style.visibility="hidden";
                    }
            </script>
        <?php
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are asking a function to check the post author role. You can use `user_can()` function.

```
if(user_can('administrator'))
{
     //Write your code if the admin
}
```

`current_user_can()` : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can

`user_can()` : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/user_can

Comment: Thanks for reply,

This is not what I am looking for. I want a function to check the post author role and remove div with class name site-shop-wrappe if post author role is not an administrator ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not that difficult to achieve. First, get an [array of all admins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users):

```
$admins = get_users (array ( 'role' => 'admin'));
```

This returns an array of user objects. You will need an array of admin ids, so you'll have to extract those:

```
$admin_ids = array();
foreach ($admins as $admin) {$admin_ids[] = $admin->ID;}
```

Next, see if the current user is in the `$admins` list and act accordingly

```
$author_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
if (in_array ($author_id, $admin_ids))
  ...do admin stuff...
else
  ...do non admin stuff...;
```

Note: I didn't test this code, some debugging may be necessary.